# Can WINC1500 be used with SPI for connecting to a router?

Tags: avr, spi, microchip, wifi

I'm planning to buy the WINC1500 WiFi module. I have heard that it contains a SPI layer, which can be used for telling the WINC1500 to connect to a router.

But as I can see in the documentation, I need to physicaly program the WINC1500 first, before I can use SPI commands with the WiFi module?

Or can I just use the SPI API protocol directly, without any programming of the WINC1500?

According to the documentation, I can use the SPI commands for doing WLAN actions, but I cannot see any example inside the documentation.

https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/ATWINC15x0-Wi-Fi-Network-Controller-Software-Design-Guide-User-Guide-DS00002389B.pdf

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The winc1500 and wilc1000 series chips do not really have sufficient documentation to use alone, but need to be paired with the Atmel ASF framework or Microchip Harmony. You can download the asf framework from Microchip, and it will have all the required drivers to do what you need.

There are two modes for the winc1500, either raw with a tcp stack like freertos+tcp, or use the socket api of the module. Setup is non trivial, it’s best to start with an existing example until you get a feel for how this works.

By setup, I mean that the sequence of initialization and connection is important, thus the need for initial reference.

Comment: Thank you. So paring the WINC1500 with other MCU like STM32 is very difficult?

Comment: https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-atwinc1500-wifi-module-breakout/wiring-and-test

Comment: Difficult is relative to experience. The asf framework is reasonable, but you have to port your SPI driver and interrupt layer. Expect a few hours here for an experienced dev, unless you find reference code. Otherwise there is no reason it can’t be done.

Comment: Added notes on setup.